# class > element selector in aphrodite

Tags: css, reactjs, aphrodite

how to implement >elemnt selector in aphrodite. I want to style my child div to width "100%"

```
 inputContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        "> div": {
            width: '100%'
        }
    },
```

but it is not working.

Comment: share html code please!

Answer (score 9):

Its a bit of a hack workaround, but I believe this should work with Aphrodite:

```
    ':nth-child(1n) > div': {
      width: '100%'
    },
```

It works because Aphrodite basically will transpose anything verbatim into the style tag it creates if you start the rule with a ":".

Comment: Note that this is is hack, and might break in future versions. 
That being said, it's the only thing that seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Use AphroditeJSS instead. It uses the same API as Aphrodite, and handles Aphrodite's some of Aphrodite shortcomings, descendant styling being one of them.

https://github.com/cssinjs/aphrodite-jss

`npm i aphrodite-jss --save-dev`

```js
const inputCss = Stylesheet.create = ({
    inputContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        "> div": {
            width: '100%'
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Aphrodite does not supported nested element styling. I would suggest using styled-components or glamorous.